# Is injecting a second Authenticity_Token on a login request considered a security threat?

Tags: authentication, csrf, token, ruby

I'm running a security test on a website. The login request looks like this:

```
    POST /sessions HTTP/1.1
    Host: example.com
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,/;q=0.8
    Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Referer: https://example.com/login/
    Cookie: guest_id=v13A143119700248937739; ga=GA1.2.2044559433.1430765006; eu_cn=1; kdt=EYxSZrzMFf9mQfhszqmTBvqOPw9yKfSG1APJHsxj; sess=BAh7CiIKZmxhc2hJQzonQWN0aW9uQ29udHJvbGxlcjo6Rmxhc2g6OkZsYXNo%250ASGFzaHsABjoKQHVzZWR7ADoPY3JlYXRlZF9hdGwrCCAI%252FD5NAToMY3NyZl9p%250AZCIlNDNiN2I5NWEyYzdkY2IyODNiNTI2MjJmN2E4OGUzYzU6B2lkIiVjZGM4%250AZDVlNjk2ZmZiOTUyMTQxNjE2YjFjYTU3NWFjODoJdXNlcmwrB%252BEaIKw%253D--472855fe8d2a70f4327cac502e1d1e916dc0d52f;
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Content-Length: 239

session%5Busername_or_email%5D=bugtest3000%40gmail.com&session%5Bpassword%5D=badpassword&authenticity_token=326c4ad687f74a52359710bad94a2bfce9e4d9d6
```

I can inject a second `authenticity_token` and still login. Is this a security issue?

```
        POST /sessions HTTP/1.1
        Host: example.com
        User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0
        Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,/;q=0.8
        Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5
        Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
        Referer: https://example.com/login/
        Cookie: guest_id=v13A143119700248937739; ga=GA1.2.2044559433.1430765006; eu_cn=1; kdt=EYxSZrzMFf9mQfhszqmTBvqOPw9yKfSG1APJHsxj; sess=BAh7CiIKZmxhc2hJQzonQWN0aW9uQ29udHJvbGxlcjo6Rmxhc2g6OkZsYXNo%250ASGFzaHsABjoKQHVzZWR7ADoPY3JlYXRlZF9hdGwrCCAI%252FD5NAToMY3NyZl9p%250AZCIlNDNiN2I5NWEyYzdkY2IyODNiNTI2MjJmN2E4OGUzYzU6B2lkIiVjZGM4%250AZDVlNjk2ZmZiOTUyMTQxNjE2YjFjYTU3NWFjODoJdXNlcmwrB%252BEaIKw%253D--472855fe8d2a70f4327cac502e1d1e916dc0d52f;
        Connection: keep-alive
        Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
        Content-Length: 239

session%5Busername_or_email%5D=bugtest3000%40gmail.com&session%5Bpassword%5D=badpassword&&scribe_log=&redirect_after_login=%2F&authenticity_token=326c4ad687f74a52359710bad94a2bfce9e4d9d5&authenticity_token=11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this attack if successful is called as `HTTP Parameter Pollution(HPP)` and the ability to inject parameters is called `HTTP Parameter Injection`. 
More on that at:
`https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_HTTP_Parameter_pollution_%28OTG-INPVAL-004%29`

Now, as far as the scenario you described is concerned, in my experience, a lot of servers will allow you to **send multiple parameters** with the same name such as your 'authenticity_token'. Some servers use the **first instance** of the value in the request and some use the **last** depending on the server. I think, the server in your case could be using the **first value**. But, to verify further and to determine its exploitability, Quoting from the OWASP Link above:

`Whether or not this default behavior reveals a potential vulnerability depends on the specific input validation and filtering specific to a particular application. As a general rule: if existing input validation and other security mechanisms are sufficient on single inputs, and if the server assigns only the first or last polluted parameters, then parameter pollution does not reveal a vulnerability. If the duplicate parameters are concatenated, different web application components use different occurrences or testing generates an error, there is an increased likelihood of being able to use parameter pollution to trigger security vulnerabilities.`

I think this explains it well. Hope that helped.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a vulnerability as shown as the system is simply taking the value of the first parameter.

An [HTTP Parameter Pollution](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_HTTP_Parameter_pollution_%28OTG-INPVAL-004%29) (HPP) vulnerability is when you can use the behaviour of the application to some advantage.

For example, in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19811699/413180) a `toAccount` parameter is injected:

```
amount=1000&fromAccount=12345&toAccount=99999
```

This is known as HTTP Parameter Injection (HPI).

This results in an HPP vulnerability on the back-end request:

```
toAccount=9876&amount=1000&fromAccount=12345&toAccount=99999
```

as the system in the example takes the second `toAccount` and redirects the bank transfer to the attacker.

If you cannot use this HPP vulnerability to your advantage, then it is not a vulnerability. Try changing the parameter order, or see if the token is used elsewhere where you can leverage this into something useable in an attack.

Comment: edited my answer keeping ur answer in mind, hope its upto the mark now, thanks.